# odp.net Add-Type error in Powershell

Tags: .net, windows, oracle, powershell

I'm trying to connect to a remote Oracle database on a RHEL node using Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.dll. But when I try to reference the dll using `Add-Type` I get the following:

`Add-Type : Could not load file or assembly Oracle.ManagedDataAccessDTC.dll' or one of its dependencies. This assembly is built by a runtime newer than the currently loaded runtime and cannot be loaded.`

The server is running on Windows Server 2008R2, my Powershell version is 2.0, and my odp.net dll is ODP.NET_Managed12.1.0.2.160719

Additional info: I am referencing the .dll from a NAS, the dll does not reside on the server.

What version of odp.net should I be using? Or what dependency am I missing? Any insight on this would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: Where is the assembly located? I will assume you have a x64 machine? What is the architecture of the library and what is the architecture of the running PowerShell instance?

Comment: The assembly is located on a NAS. The OS is 64bit.

Comment: OK. So what about PS and the DLL? I just want to be sure it is not an architecture mismatch.

Answer (score 0):

"This assembly is built by a runtime newer..."

Try installing a new version of PowerShell.

With PowerShell 5.1 I have installed .Net version 4.5.2

But now I have another error "Could not load file or assembly"... I'm working on it ;-)